# Spring compression problem

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

A block of mass $m = 1.5$kg is dropped from height $h = 85$cm onto a spring of spring constant $k=1910$N/m. Find the maximum distance the spring is compressed.

[image]

**This is what I did:**

$$19.1 + (\sqrt{ 19.1 ^2 + 2(19.1)(0.85)(1910)} ) /  1910$$

Yet it's wrong. *What's the issue?*

Answer (score 1):

Try that. You have that $m = 1,5$kg, $h = 0,85$m and $k = 1910$N/m. Then use that you must have conservation of energy.

$$E_i = E_f$$

$$mg(h + \delta x) = \frac{1}{2}k(\delta x)^2 \implies \delta x^2 - A\delta x - Ah$$

For $A := 2mg/k  = 0,015706$ such that $\Delta = 0,05464707$ and $\sqrt{\Delta} = 0,231618$ then you will have that the maximum displacement will be

> $$\delta x^{max} = 0,12366$$

Try that value

Comment: Are you using the decimal comma instead of the decimal point?

Comment: Yes. $1/10 = 0,1$

Comment: That's not how they write numbers in English, though.

Comment: This is completely irrelevant

Comment: Not sure what point you are trying to make with your commas, but this site uses English and that extends to how numbers are written.  Do I wish a uniform convention had developed?  I do, but it hasn't and you can see it also in the unsightly space after the comma.  Then again, the world faces more serious issues than this, and if those commas keep you happy, carry on.